# Scope of dictionary passed in render_to_response

Tags: python, django, render-to-response

```
def func(user):
    templatename="login.html"
    return render_to_response(templatename,{'user':user},context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

What is the **scope of the dictionary** passed in the render_to_response function in django ? Means could we only use that dictionary in the login.html template or else any template of our app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of your `dict` is within `login.html` only.

If you want to use access to the `user` in your template, use something like this:

```
{{user}}
```

If you want to have a dict with a scope in any template, use context processors

add this in your
**Settings.py**

```
import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'utils.custom_context_processors.my_context_processor',
)
```

create a folder in your project root dir, lets name it "utils", inside the folder create **init**.py file and custom_context_processors.py

```
   +apps
   ....other folders.
   +utils
      ---__init__.py
      ---custom_context_processors.py
```

**custom_context_processors.py**

```
def my_context_processor(request):
      your_custom_dict = {...}
      return your_custom_dict
```

With that, `your_custom_dict` will be available in any template.

Note: If you only want to access to the user in any place, just do `{{request.user}}`

Comment: So how can we use it throughout our app? @levi

Comment: And what if it is something other than user.? @levi